# Customizing index and using doc package

Tags: indexing

I needed an index for my master thesis and wanted to adjust the index with a style file. It took me 3 hours to get it working with the template I am using. My style file was always ignored until I've found out that the problem is caused by including the `doc` package.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
% \usepackage{doc} % somehow changes the index, indexname etc.

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\index{bla} bla.
\index{blub} blub.

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\def\indexname{Stichwortverzeichnis}
\makeatletter
\printindex
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

I've uploaded my index style file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15732252/gind.ist), but I doubt that this is a problem with my index style file?!

To compile you'll need to do (assuming you will save the example to 'index.tex' and the index style file to 'gind.ist'):

```
latex index.tex

makeindex -s gind.ist -g index # or another index style

latex index.tex
latex index.tex

dvips index.dvi
ps2pdf index.ps
```

Here the result with the `doc` package (ingoring my index style file):
[image: with <code>doc</code> package]
And here the result without the `doc` package (using my index style file):
[image: without <code>doc</code> package]

My question: Is this an explicit behaviour of the `doc` package or is it a nasty side-effect of the package? I've just read the short explanation of the package on CTAN but couldn't answer this question by myself.

Comment: Actually, I dunno. It was just in my template (from my university) and narrowed this behaviour down to this package.

I think it should be [this](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/doc) `doc` package

I can't see why this should change the index?!

Comment: `\usepackage{doc} % Fuer's BibTeX-Logo (for BibTeX-Logo)`

So in the template it was just included for the BibTeX-Logo

Comment: Thanks, but you also don't see why importing `doc` would lead to such a strange behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The used package `doc` is part of `docstrip` which is used to typeset the documentation of LaTeX packages. Try for example `texdoc babel` and check the index in that documentation (three columns). In your given MWE you also get an index with three columns you don't want.

As you said in the comments you use package `doc` only to get a proper macro for BibTeX. You can use `\newcommand*{\BibTeX}{\textsc{Bib}\TeX{}}` to create the BibTeX logo by your own or if you need more LaTeX logos use package [hologos](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/hologo.pdf) to get ready-for-use-macros.